# How to get raster layer name in GDAL?

Tags: raster, gdal, file-path

I have a path of a raster layer. I want to get name of this layer in GDAL.
In below code I want to get `aa.tif`

```
from osgeo import gdal

dataset = gdal.Open("/Data/raster/aa.tif")
print dataset.GetName()
```

But I received below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpq3Peqi.py", line 5, in <module>
    print dataset.GetName()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 1804, in <lambda>
    __getattr__ = lambda self, name: _swig_getattr(self, Dataset, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 74, in _swig_getattr
    return _swig_getattr_nondynamic(self, class_type, name, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 69, in _swig_getattr_nondynamic
    return object.__getattr__(self, name)
AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Where's the documentation for "GetName()"? Or was that a guess, because there's a `GetName` for *ogr* data sources? Can't you keep the filename somewhere and get the name part from that?

Comment: Hi @Spacedman, Your're right. `GetName' is not for gdal data sources. No unfortunately in my long code I receive a list of path raster layers and for next steps need only raster layer names.

Comment: You mean "a list of paths *of* raster layers"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Gdal for that. Check out os.path and the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304117/split-filenames-with-python#7304165.

Answer (score 5):

`GetDescription` returns the full path:

```
>>> import osgeo
>>> from osgeo import gdal
>>> d = gdal.Open("./swb/srtm_38_04.tif")
>>> d.GetDescription()
'./swb/srtm_38_04.tif'
>>>
```

then use standard python path munging tools to get the name.

Comment: Sorry I think I couldn't ask clearly my question. For example In your code I have `'./swb/srtm_38_04.tif'` fullpath, In fact I want only `srtm_38_04.tif` or `srtm_38_04`.

Comment: You may also try `d.GetMetadata('DERIVED_SUBDATASETS')` but it will return full path to. You have to use `os.path.basename` to get file name from path.

Comment: @nickan that's what I meant by "standard python path munging tools", like `os.path.split`, as mentioned in the accepted answer. Your question made it seem like you wanted the path from a GDAL Dataset object.

Comment: @Spacedman, you 're right. It was better I asked my question in other place, but because I used gdal in my code I thought it ask here, sorry.